# Capture data on modem

Tags: java, telephony, modem, at-command, rxtx

I am using a USB telephone modem and trying to connect to another modem by dialing a number. I could dial the number using rxtx library. Once the callee answers I believe it's trying to switch to data mode (I could hear screeching sound). Is there any way to capture the raw data that are being transacted? Is there any AT command to do this?

Can someone explain or provide any reference to learn what happens during this screeching sound?

Thanks for your help!